# meaning of "Opening Day slate"

Tags: meaning

[From a post](https://www.cbssports.com/mlb/news/mlb-schedule-full-list-of-2020-opening-day-games-other-dates-to-circle-during-60-game-season/live/)

> There are 14 games on Friday's **Opening Day slate**

I know what [Opening Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opening_Day) is and understand the items of "slate" on [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=slate)

> 1. A fine-grained metamorphic rock that splits into thin, smooth-surfaced layers.
> 2. a. A piece of this rock cut for use as roofing or surfacing material or as a writing surface. b. A writing tablet made of a
>    similar material.
> 3. A record of past performance or activity: start over with a clean slate.
> 4. A list of the candidates of a political party running for various offices.
> 5. A dark or bluish gray to dark bluish or dark purplish gray.

I guess Opening Day slate is some kind of list like this?

[image]

In the example of 2020 Opening Day slate, there are 14 items/games in it, giving the basic information for each of them.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a metaphorical use of the meaning "A piece of this rock cut for use as ... a writing surface."

A slate of this kind was can be written on with chalk and then easily erased. In this sense, *slate* is a synonym for *blackboard* or *chalkboard*.

One thing you might use this for is to provide information that changes daily, like the games to be played in a sports league.

Comment: Thank you. With this particular meaning, do "schedule" and "slate" mean the same thing?

Comment: In this particular usage they do. In general you wouldn't talk about a "slate" for the month or for the season. At least not without some particular context that makes it clear what you mean.